# Wake on Linux Xubuntu.16.04.1

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management

MSI notebook GP72-6QE 254XFR with Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (linux 4.4.0.42 X86_64)
System on SSD. Swap on HDD.
Swap size > memory size.
Graphics cards:

```
NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42
```

Suspending the nobebook is successful in closing the screen.
But, wake up on the PC is done by touching the mouse.
2 errors messages zipping lines in the wake:

```
dpm_run_callback() : usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -32
PM: Device 1-7 failed to resume async: error -32
```

How to set wake on PC only with the power button ? (and not with the mouse)
What match these two lines of errors ?
Thank you.